# Trying to install PEAR on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, terminal, pear

Can anybody advise me how I can install PEAR on my MAC?

Attempt 1:

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear | sudo php
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 88959  100 88959    0     0  70283      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  200k
Sorry!  Your PHP version is too new (5.3.8) for this go-pear.
Instead use http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar for a more stable and current
version of go-pear, more suited to your PHP version.

Thank you for your coopertion and sorry for the inconvenience!
```

Attempt 2:

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar | sudo php
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3594k  100 3594k    0     0  1150k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 1351k

Warning: Phar::mapPhar(-): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 1119
unable to open phar for reading "-"
Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in - on line 1236
```

Attempt 3 (from http://sudhanshuraheja.com/2011/03/installing-php-pear-on-mac-osx-10-6-with-php-5-3-3/):

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar
-bash: go-pear.phar: Permission denied
```

I am trying to install phpUnit, but I can't do this without pear.

Comment: http://kubyshkin.ru/programming/phpunit-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10-6/

Answer (score 5):

The last one is on the right track: you can't use the `curl|php` method with newer versions (which is why the docs no longer suggest it).

And the error message from bash should tell you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to save a file called `go-pear.phar`, and you don't have permission to do so. Most likely this is because you've `cd`'d into a directory you don't have write permission for, like `/`.

One solution is to do this:

```
curl https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > ~/go-pear.phar
sudo php ~/go-pear.phar
```

Even simpler, if you open a new Terminal you'll end up in ~, and you can follow the instructions exactly as-is and they'll work.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal 
    `$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`

after download in terminal.  This is for people using PHP 5.4

```
$ php -q go-pear.phar
```